# I think some thing went wrong with `viewed` count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

Today i posted one question . After some time i got three up vote on that question .
But view count was 2 only  SO how it possible . 
I also try to refresh page many time . Event see same link on different system its show me same thing .

[My question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146180/event-position-not-proper-fit-on-days-column-on-moving-time-in-jquery-week-calen)

and look at screen shot below .

[image]

Comment: I wonder, do reviews count as views?

Comment: I can see 4 views. AFAIK views are also cached.

Comment: @hims056 that's because people just clicked to view. I clicked and saw 2 as well, when this post was submitted.

Comment: `@hims056` have look at screen shot with this question..

Comment: The view count is cached; it is not updated in real time.

Comment: The question page is cached.